# Finding the next available date from a Dataframe for group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, group-by

I have a data frame that contains 1 minutes OHLC stock data(length = 22879). It has times that are greater than 16:00 or less than 9:30. I am trying to find the extended hours max high and min low for each individual extended hour session. Since the market closes at 4 and opens up at 9:30 I have this to filter the time. An example, the extended hours for 9/28/2022 technically starts at 9/27/2022 at 16:00 and goes until 9/28/2022 9:30.

[image]

```
NonMarketHours = minuteData.loc[(minuteData['times'] > datetime.time(hour=15, minute=59)) | (minuteData['times'] < datetime.time(hour=9, minute=30))]
```

This is what the filtered DataFrame Looks like.

In order to get the Extended hours correctly I have this code where if the time for the row is greater than 16:00 then add 1 day to the date and create a new column of that date. If the time is less than 9:30 then it will just have the current date in the column. Unless it is Friday when it adds 3 days because the market will open back up on Monday which would be in three days. The issue I am running into is when there is a holiday in the middle of the week. For example, the market is closed every third Thursday of November for thanks giving. The issue I am running into is that when the date is 11/25/2020 which is a Wednesday the next available date is 11/27/2020 (Friday) because it is closed on Thursday 11/26/2020.

```
conditions = [(NonMarketHours['time'] > datetime.time(hour=15, minute=59)) & (NonMarketHours['dayOfWeek'] < 4), (NonMarketHours['time'] > datetime.time(hour=15, minute=59)) & (NonMarketHours['dayOfWeek']== 4)]
choices = [NonMarketHours['date'] + timedelta(days=1),NonMarketHours['date'] + timedelta(days=3)]

NonMarketHours["new date"] = np.select(conditions, choices, NonMarketHours['date'])
```

My question. Is there away to search the dataframe for the next available date after it knows the current date. For example the `new date` for 11/25/2020 when time is greater than 16:00 is 11/26/2020. However I want it to return 11/27/2020 because that is the next available date in the DataFrame

This is how the DF currently looks:

```
timestamp   date    time    dayOfWeek   times   new date
11/25/2020 19:57    11/25/2020  19:57:00    2   19:57:00    11/26/2020
11/25/2020 19:58    11/25/2020  19:58:00    2   19:58:00    11/26/2020
11/25/2020 19:59    11/25/2020  19:59:00    2   19:59:00    11/26/2020
11/25/2020 20:00    11/25/2020  20:00:00    2   20:00:00    **11/26/2020**
**11/27/2020** 4:01 11/27/2020  4:01:00 4   4:01:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:02 11/27/2020  4:02:00 4   4:02:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:03 11/27/2020  4:03:00 4   4:03:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:04 11/27/2020  4:04:00 4   4:04:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:05 11/27/2020  4:05:00 4   4:05:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:06 11/27/2020  4:06:00 4   4:06:00 11/27/2020
```

This is what I want the DF to look like
You can see that the new date is 11/27/2020 because that is the next data from the data fram

```
timestamp   date    time    dayOfWeek   times   new date
11/25/2020 19:57    11/25/2020  19:57:00    2   19:57:00    11/27/2020
11/25/2020 19:58    11/25/2020  19:58:00    2   19:58:00    11/27/2020
11/25/2020 19:59    11/25/2020  19:59:00    2   19:59:00    11/27/2020
11/25/2020 20:00    11/25/2020  20:00:00    2   20:00:00    **11/27/2020**
**11/27/2020** 4:01 11/27/2020  4:01:00 4   4:01:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:02 11/27/2020  4:02:00 4   4:02:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:03 11/27/2020  4:03:00 4   4:03:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:04 11/27/2020  4:04:00 4   4:04:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:05 11/27/2020  4:05:00 4   4:05:00 11/27/2020
11/27/2020 4:06 11/27/2020  4:06:00 4   4:06:00 11/27/2020
```

I want new date to be the next data in the dataFrame.

Otherwise my code works when there is no holiday. Example:

```
timestamp   date    time    dayOfWeek   times   new date
11/24/2020 19:54    11/24/2020  19:54:00    1   19:54:00    11/25/2020
11/24/2020 19:55    11/24/2020  19:55:00    1   19:55:00    11/25/2020
11/24/2020 19:56    11/24/2020  19:56:00    1   19:56:00    11/25/2020
11/24/2020 19:57    11/24/2020  19:57:00    1   19:57:00    11/25/2020
11/24/2020 19:58    11/24/2020  19:58:00    1   19:58:00    11/25/2020
11/24/2020 19:59    11/24/2020  19:59:00    1   19:59:00    11/25/2020
11/25/2020 4:01 11/25/2020  4:01:00 2   4:01:00 11/25/2020
11/25/2020 4:02 11/25/2020  4:02:00 2   4:02:00 11/25/2020
11/25/2020 4:03 11/25/2020  4:03:00 2   4:03:00 11/25/2020
11/25/2020 4:04 11/25/2020  4:04:00 2   4:04:00 11/25/2020
11/25/2020 4:06 11/25/2020  4:06:00 2   4:06:00 11/25/2020
11/25/2020 4:07 11/25/2020  4:07:00 2   4:07:00 11/25/2020
11/25/2020 4:08 11/25/2020  4:08:00 2   4:08:00 11/25/2020
11/25/2020 4:09 11/25/2020  4:09:00 2   4:09:00 11/25/2020
```

You can see that is works as expected because the new date is the next days date but I had to calculate it manually instead of just looking at what the next date is.

Please let me know if I need to be more clear and if I need to put more of my own code in this question.

In order to find the max of highs and min of lows from this I am then grouping by the new date

```
PMData = NonMarketHours.groupby('new date').agg({'low': 'min', 'high': 'max'})[['low', 'high']].reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question. Is there away to search the dataframe for the next
> available date after it knows the current date

Question: what should be the next date for the last date in your DF?
In below solution, its NaN at the moment

```
# create a df by finding the unique dates
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df['date']), columns=['current'])

# find the next date in the list of dates using shift
df2['next']=df2['current'].shift(-1)

# use df2 as a dictionary to map the date to the next date
df['Next Date'] = df['date'].map(df2.set_index('current')['next'])
df
```

```
          timestamp           date    time  dayOfWeek   times   new date    Next Date
0   11/25/2020 19:57    11/25/2020  19:57:00    2   19:57:00    11/26/2020  11/27/2020
1   11/25/2020 19:58    11/25/2020  19:58:00    2   19:58:00    11/26/2020  11/27/2020
2   11/25/2020 19:59    11/25/2020  19:59:00    2   19:59:00    11/26/2020  11/27/2020
3   11/25/2020 20:00    11/25/2020  20:00:00    2   20:00:00    **11/26/2020**  11/27/2020
4   11/27/2020 4:01     11/27/2020  4:01:00     4   4:01:00     11/27/2020  NaN
5   11/27/2020 4:02     11/27/2020  4:02:00     4   4:02:00     11/27/2020  NaN
6   11/27/2020 4:03     11/27/2020  4:03:00     4   4:03:00     11/27/2020  NaN
7   11/27/2020 4:04     11/27/2020  4:04:00     4   4:04:00     11/27/2020  NaN
8   11/27/2020 4:05     11/27/2020  4:05:00     4   4:05:00     11/27/2020  NaN
9   11/27/2020 4:06     11/27/2020  4:06:00     4   4:06:00     11/27/2020  NaN
```

In absence of next date, if you like to substitute the date

```
df['Next Date'] = df['date'].map(df2.set_index('current')['next']).fillna(df['date'])
df
```

Comment: But I have it from the start of 9/28/2020 to 9/23/2022 so it needs to do it throughout the DF

Comment: so, you;re looking for a current date and the next date?

Comment: i need the date of the next day in the data frame not of just one single date

Comment: @svlad, posted an updated solution. is that what you were looking for?